# Unable to find MOSFET type and specs

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Recently I've been trying to fix a motor-controling board in my pool cleaner. After some measuring, I've figured out, that two MOSFETs are behaving strangely and their behaviour varies from the other two paires.

[image]

Unfortunately I am unable to find the types and specs of the FETs. This is what is written on them:

1. D409 BA6X17
2. VNH38 ON 58 65NLG

Isn't someone familiar with these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ON semiconductor device is a [NVD5865NL](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NVD5865NL-D.PDF): -

[image]

The other device: -

[image]

Looks like it has the Alpha & Omega Semiconductor symbol: -

[image]

I thinks it's the [AOD409](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD409.pdf): -

[image]

Comment: AOD -> Aodele -> Joy enters the house ? :-)

Comment: Might that be Ayodele Mr. McMahon?

Comment: Close enough, sir :-) -> Ayodelé.